# Group by ID and complet time series Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a pandas Dataframe with observations of one ID and I have a problem similar to the one solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823273/counting-frequency-of-values-by-date-using-pandas).

```
Timestamp              ID
2014-10-16 15:05:17    123
2014-10-16 14:56:37    148
2014-10-16 14:25:16    123
2014-10-16 14:15:32    123
2014-10-16 13:41:01    123
2014-10-16 12:50:30    148
2014-10-16 12:28:54    123
2014-10-16 12:26:56    123
2014-10-16 12:25:12    123
...
2014-10-08 15:52:49    150
2014-10-08 15:04:50    150
2014-10-08 15:03:48    148
2014-10-08 15:02:27    200
2014-10-08 15:01:56    236
2014-10-08 13:27:28    147
2014-10-08 13:01:08    148
2014-10-08 12:52:06    999
2014-10-08 12:43:27    999
Name: summary, Length: 600
```

On the mentioned post they show how to group by ID and also how to make the count.Using `df['Week/Year'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: "%d/%d" % (x.week, x.year))` I have now this:

```
   Timestamp               ID     Week/Year
0  2014-10-16 15:05:17     123    42/2014
1  2014-10-16 14:56:37     150    42/2014
2  2014-10-16 14:25:16     123    42/2014
```

My problem is that now I want to make a time series so, actually, I need:

```
Category    Week_42_2014    Week_43_2014    Week_44_2014    
123         7              0              6
150         0              0              2              ...
```

This is, I need the weeks as a column, the categories as rows and also fill the gaps of the weeks with no observations. In my case I also need days, but I guess that it is really similar.

Thanks,

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate because it was not clear my question. I don't want just to pivot the data, I also aim to fill the missing weeks, days without observations with 0 for all the IDs. I change the original explanation to make myself more clear.

Comment: I rolled back your edit as you shouldn't *change* your question in substance after you have answer(s). Instead, ask a new question with a **[mcve]** so that these problems don't occur.

Comment: It was already in the text ("and also fill the gaps of the weeks with no observations"), I just make it more clear. So, in my opinion, the substance of the question is not changed. But ok, I'll try to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Week/Year', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

print(res)

          Timestamp        
Week/Year   41/2014 42/2014
ID                         
123               0       7
147               1       0
148               2       2
150               2       0
200               1       0
236               1       0
999               2       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.crosstab` in doing the task

```
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2014-10-16 15:05:17 ',end='2014-11-08 12:43:27 ',freq='D')
df['value'] = np.repeat([11,22,33,44],len(df)/3)[:len(df)]
df['week'] = df.date.dt.week
df['Year'] = df.date.dt.year



df = pd.crosstab(df.value,[df.week,df.Year])
df.columns = 'Week_' +df.columns.levels[0].astype(str)+"_" +df.columns.levels[1].astype(str)
```

Out:

```
    Week_42_2014    Week_43_2014    Week_44_2014    Week_45_2014
value               
11  4   3   0   0
22  0   4   3   0
33  0   0   4   3
44  0   0   0   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key = 'Timestamp', freq = 'W')] ['ID'].count().\
        to_frame().rename(columns = {'ID' : 'counts'}).reset_index()
```

Then `pivot`:

```
df.pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'Timestamp', values = 'counts')
```

This would ofcourse, return column names as the first day if the respective week; you can change these by replacing `df.columns` with a list of your desired column names.

EDIT:

If you already have a column of weeks, you can just use `pd.pivot_table` without doing a `groupby`.